# Eager load for collections on the fly

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this, user has many to many property via pivot property_users.

I am making somehow **reusable classes** in my webapp.

These are the models with their eager loading functions:

```
//User model
public function properties()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class, 'property_users', 'user_id', 'property_id');
}

//Property model
public function property_users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PropertyUser::class, 'property_id', 'id');
}

//PropertyUser model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

//GetProperties class
public function handle()
{
    return auth()->user()->properties()->get();
}

//somewhere in a feature
$properties = $this->run(GetProperties::class);
//this returns valid properties under the logged in user
```

I now need to get the chat_username in property_users that belongs to this user

I manage to make it work if I loop through the properties and then doing it on the fly.

```
$properties = $properties->map(function($property) {
    $propertyUsers = $property->property_users()->get();

    $chatUsername = null;
    foreach($propertyUsers as $propertyUser) {
        if($propertyUser->property_id == $property->id) {
           $chatUsername = $propertyUser->chat_username;
        }
    }

    return [
        'name' => $property->name,
        'id' => $property->id,
        'chat_username' => $chatUsername
    ];
});
```

But I am trying to **reduce query on loop to reduce hits especially when they are on multiple properties in the database**.

The other way is that I can add the property_users in the eager loading under GetProperties class by updating it to:

```
$query = Property::query();

$query->with(['property_users']);

$query->whereHas('property_users', function($qry) {
    $qry->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
});

$properties = $query->get();

return $properties;
```

But I do **not want to rely on adding more eager loading to the original GetProperties class as the GetProperties will get fat** and I do not really need those data (let's say adding property_invoices, property_schedules, etc but not really needing it in some area).

Rather, I want to do the eager loading on the fly but with a twist! This is how I would imagine it:

Collect all the ids from the properties, do the fetch using **wherein** and apply all the users to the properties in a single query. This way it will be even more beautiful.

Maybe something like this: (using the original GetProperties class)

```
$properties = $this->run(GetProperties::class);
//this does not work. The error is: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::property_users does not exist.
$property->property_users = $properties->property_users()->get();
```

Would be great if someone can show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after reading here and there.

I found this article: https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-eager-loading

The solution is really nice. Simply:

```
$properties = $this->run(GetProperties::class);

//lazy load
$properties->load('property_users');

$properties = $properties->map(function($property) {
    $user = $property->property_users->first(function($user) {
        if($user->user_id == Auth::user()->id) {
            return $user;
        }
    })->only('chat_username');

    return [
        'name' => $property->name,
        'id' => $property->id,
        'chat_username' => $user['chat_username']
    ];
});
```

After checking query logs:

```
//auth query done by middleware
[2019-05-21 07:59:11] local.INFO: select * from `users` where `auth_token` = ? or `temporary_auth_token` = ? limit 1 ["token_removed_for_security_purpose","token_removed_for_security_purpose"] 
//These are the queries made:
[2019-05-21 07:59:11] local.INFO: select `properties`.*, `property_users`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `property_users`.`property_id` as `pivot_property_id` from `properties` inner join `property_users` on `properties`.`id` = `property_users`.`property_id` where `property_users`.`user_id` = ? [8] 
[2019-05-21 07:59:11] local.INFO: select * from `property_users` where `property_users`.`property_id` in (2, 4)
```

This way, I can keep my GetProperties as small as possible, then just lazy load it whereever I need it.

Answer (score 0):

What about eager loading only the fields you actually need?

```
$query->with('property_users:id,user_id');
```

The model will not get fat, and you will not need to do separate queries in the loop.

It is documented in the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading , see **Eager Loading Specific Columns**

Edit: if you want to perform the query **after** the GetProperties class, you will need to collect all the ids and perform a second query. I honestly don't like this second approach, because it is far slower, less performant and I consider it less elegant then adding a single line in the GetProperties class, but it is gonna work:

```
$properties = $this->run(GetProperties::class);
$ids = $properties->pluck('id'); // Get all the ids as an array
$propertyUsers = propertyUsers::whereIn('property_id', $ids)->get(); // Get the propertyUsers model
foreach($properties as $property) {
    $property->property_users = $propertyUsers->where('property_id', $property->id); // Not even sure you can do that, proerty_users may not been writable
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, sorry not the model, but the GetProperties class itself will get fat.

Comment: Technically, that is still adding it to the GetProperties class. How about to add it outside where it is being used like in a controller or a feature. For a record (by doing looping) it will work, but that I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I edited the answer, but I'm gonna be honest and say to you that I consider it a far worse approach

Comment: You could add a flag to the GetProperties constructor, and only perform the eager loading when needed

Comment: $property->property_users is just newly added attribute not the original, it will somehow work, but there you will still need to several collection()->map and return, But again it is abit lengthy, I am wondering and asking maybe Laravel has something like this and we ought to know as it will be a good skill coz will be using it quite alot.

Will check and wait on other answers to compare. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is not a native way in laravel to perform that, `$properties` is a collection and you see all the functions available here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods

Comment: Thank you for putting time and effort. I found the solution. Cheers!